# Django rest view retrieve chained objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have models with following relationships: A 'User' can have a 'Wishlist' and a 'Wishlist' will have many 'Book's.

I want to retrieve all the books in a specific user's wishlist. I am writing my view like following:

```
# Get specific user's wishlist
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def wishlist(request):
    """
    List all the boosk in wishlist of a specific user
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        books = Wishlist.objects.filter(request.user)
        serializer = BookSerializer(books, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

How can I write logic inside my filter? Or could there be a better approach (e.g. not serializing books instead wishlist)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be querying for Books, not Wishlists:

```
books = Book.objects.filter(wishlist__user=request.user)
```

Comment: I though so as well. Thanks for your quick response :)